# useEffect retornando null

Tags: react, api, return, null, native

Estou iniciando com React Native, porém estou com dificuldades para obter uma lista ao carregar a tela utilizando `useEffect`, sempre que inicializa a tela a primeira vez, o `setList` retorna vazio, e quando clico no botão para atualizar, retorna os dados normalmente.

Alguém pode me explicar por que isso acontece? Olhei a documentação do `useEffect` e realmente a primeira vez que é chamado, retorna nulo, mas não entendi o porque na minha chamada o mesmo não retorna os dados da API.
Ressaltando que quando clico no botão "refresh", os dados retornam normalmente.

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

const handleTotals = async () => {

        setLoading(true);
        setList([]);
        
        let res = await Api.getOrderTotals();

        if(res.data) {

            setList(res.data);

        }

        setLoading(false);

    }
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        
        setName();
        handleTotals();        
        console.log(list);        //Retorna nulo

    }, [])
```

Comment: `handleTotals` é uma funcão assíncrona, você tem que esperar ela ser concluida para dar um console.log

Comment: @CmteCardeal, como posso utilizar o await dentro do useEffect? Já tentei aqui e nada por enquanto. Agradeço a resposta!

Comment: @CmteCardeal sim, continua nulo! :(

Answer (score 1):

Da forma como você esta utilizando o `useEffect` ele irá executar somente durante a primeira renderização do seu componente, como seu `list` depende de uma chamada assíncrona ele vai possuir o valor inicial que você atribuiu. se você quiser ver os valores no seu `console.log` recomendo que você coloque fora do seu `useEffect`, por exemplo:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setName();
        handleTotals();        
    }, [])

console.log(list);
```

Dessa forma assim que sua chamada for finalizada e o `setList` for chamado seu componente irá renderizar com o estado atualizado, é importante você entender que o `useEffect` não irá ser executado durante essa segunda renderização.

Comment: Jà tentei desta forma também, permanece nulo! :(

Comment: Existe mais algum trecho do seu código que você executa um `setList` ?

Comment: coloquei num repositorio do github:
https://github.com/ThiagoxxLive/z1app/blob/master/src/screens/Dashboard/index.js

Answer (score -2):

```js
async function loadTotals(){
   setName();
   // deve aguardar finalizar a requisição, tambem é possível utilizando o `.then`
   await handleTotals();        
   console.log(list);
}

useEffect(() => {
   loadTotals()    
}, [loadTotals])
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121131/discussion-on-answer-by-raphael-kieling-tondin-useeffect-retornando-null)